# How to load images that aren't on the screen

Tags: android, layout, gridview, scroll, adapter

I currently have a gridview that displays some thumbnail images. The problem I am running into is that when I scroll through the images I can see the images switch from old to new as they are being replaced. So, I was wondering how I would fix this. Is there a way to load images that aren't on the screen so when I scroll the user doesn't have to see the change in images?

Comment: that is the listview recycling its view, you probably need to look at lazyloading images

Comment: Why don't you just create bitmaps and draw them when necessary? Creating bitmap takes the image to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid that effect is to set the image first to `null` in the `getView()` method of your adapter. You can then check an LRU cache if the image is already loaded. If yes, then set it right away, if not then load it asynchronous as a bitmap. Set it to the view and add it to the LRU cache.

Comment: I'm using Universal Image Loader to cache my images and to check if they are cached. I want to try and use UIL if possible. However, I am running into the problem that I have to set the bitmap to a URI so UIL can process the image. So if I cache it beforehand as you suggested I will have no URI to pass into the UIL. Do you see anyway around this?

Comment: You don't need to cache the images beforehand, only when they get displayed the first time. You see the images changing in the ImageView, because the ImageLoader loads them async. Just clear them first by setting the image to null in the ImageView. The images will still appear a bit delayed, but at least you won't see the old one first.